# NSFetchedResultsController with data from other model

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to build app with UITableView with data from NSFetchedResultsController. The problem is - I need to show some additional data from other models in table view.

Assume I have 2 models: Students and Groups (I think the relation is obvious: group consists of many students and student can be only in one group). I'm trying to build UITableView with list of groups. I would also like number of students in each group.

```
(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchController {
   if (!_fetchController) {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GroupModel" inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *messageInChatPredicate = [GroupModel getMyChatsPredicate];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:messageInChatPredicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    _fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"main"];
    _fetchController.delegate = self;
  }

  return _fetchController;
}
```

I wonder how I can I add additional information (such as number of students in each group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `group.students.count` to get the value from the `group` entity?  You only need one fetchedResultsController and I think you will find Core Data performance is fine.

Your terminology is a bit confusing, usually a model is a core data model created in Xcode and has a number of entities e.g. Group, Student. Sometimes you can use two different models and/or different versions of the models.

Your objects are usually know as Entities and both would belong to the same Core Data model.

EDIT: 
To get the count of subgroups, such as girls or boys you can do the following

```
NSMutableArray *boys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender = %@",@"MALE"];
[boys addObjectsFromArray:[group.students filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@" boys count is %d", boys.count);
```

Assuming of course that `gender` is an attribute of `Student`.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code how to fetch group.students.count along with group object? I think your advice is what I actually need, but I can't get additional info with my current request.

Comment: Just fetch the group and then use group.students.count to get the count.

Comment: Sorry, doing that from my iPhone!  I assume your existing GroupModel fetchedResultsController works fine and returns the student groups you want and I assume you have set up the core data relationships properly.  Then if you want to display the number of students in each group in your configureCell method construct a label using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%d)", group.groupName, group.students.count);`

You may need to be a bit more specific about the issue you are having if this explanation misses the mark.

Comment: the problem here is you cannot make a specific query for students. For example, I'd like to show number of boys and girls in each group.

Comment: See the EDIT in my answer above on how to get a subgroup from the students array.

Answer (score 1):

Create another NSFetchedResultsController that is responsible for the other model (i.e student).

Comment: As far as I understand there will be a lot of problems with their synchronization: if I NSFetchedResultsChangeMove in one of them, I have to move rows in others and etc...

Answer (score -1):

You have basically two options to get additional information such as the number of students in each group.

The first option is to count the students in the Group-Student relation. To serve this request the NSManagedObjectContext will load all students in memory to get a suitable result. Personally, I don't really like this option.

The second option is to store the number of students who belong to a group in a property of the group so that it can be directly add. Yes, you have to maintain the correct number manually. Depending on the amount of data that has to be loaded, this approach is more preferable. Crucially since it's way fas

Comment: I think adding "caching" property to group model is ok, but IMO it is early optimization, that would require a lot of code.

Comment: I'll extend my answer to explain why this is bad idea: every modification of student entity should update parents entity.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald if we are talking about simple application without external updates (ex, without push notifications) it can be short. But when data can be updated from internet code becomes more complex

Comment: If you are inserting students objects and setting a group on them using Core Data then a few lines of code to set an additional attribute on the group entity would be something like `group.studentCount = group.students.count` called from a setter on group. Shouldn't matter where the data gets updated from if you are using Core Data.